# tcolorbox line numbers

Tags: minted, tcolorbox, line-numbering

I am trying to make a generic environment to use for all my boxes in my document. I want all my boxes to have line numbers. I can only get this to work some of the time. I don't get line numbers when I use minted content in the box.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted, breakable, skins}

\definecolor{darkgray}{gray}{0.15}
\definecolor{gray}{gray}{0.30}

\newenvironment{mylisting}[1]
{
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        title=#1,
        listing only,
        breakable,
        colframe=gray,
        colbacktitle=gray,
        colback=darkgray,
        enhanced,
        left=0.3125in,
        overlay={
            \begin{tcbclipinterior}
                \fill[gray] (frame.south west) rectangle ([xshift=0.25in]frame.north west);
            \end{tcbclipinterior}}]
        \begin{internallinenumbers}
}
{
        \end{internallinenumbers}
    \end{tcolorbox}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{mylisting}{Test Line Numbers}
        Test

        the

        line

        numbers.
    \end{mylisting}
    \begin{mylisting}{Test Minted Line Numbers}
        \mint{cpp}|hi|
    \end{mylisting}
\end{document}
```

The first usage works, but the second usage with the `\mint` command does not. What am I missing?

PS - I'm aware that minted can do its own line numbering, but I wanted to handle line numbering in a centralized way, and not everything in a listing will be minted, so I figured the line numbering could be decoupled from minted.

Comment: I think that this is purely about interaction between `lineno` and `minted` (independent of `tcolorbox`). I just made some tests and it seems that `internallinenumbers` has no effect on any `minted` content. Maybe, someone know how to change that (?)

Comment: Interesting. I didn't notice that. Good catch. I wonder if it is just minted, or other similar things too.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm Any news about this?

Comment: @egreg No, I don't think so. `lineno` and `minted` are not compatible as far as I know.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm Has anything changed now?

Comment: @TeXnician No, nothing changed on my system - I just checked with a recently updated distribution. Are there some hints that `lineno` and `minted` are made compatible?

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm No, there aren't. It just was out of interest as I currently work-around the problem with Lua (without `lineno`).